# Falha ao chamar php no submit de um botão

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando executar um script php no submit de um botão, mas o php é chamado recebo um erro no inlcude - "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ", chamei o php por um include fora do botão e funcionou mas quando tento colocar ele no botão da esse erro.

html

```
<a href="#!" class="modal-close btn-flat">Cancelar</a>
<a href="Chamadas/remover.php"><button  class="btn cyan" type="submit">Excluir</button></a>
```

include no php que reproduzem o erro quando eu chamo somente pelo botão - nome do arquivo remove.php

```
include_once("DAO/dalA.php");
include_once("Classes/classA.php");
```

Comment: Não te um formulário, é apenas o botão

Comment: Reignomo, é meio perigo simplesmente chamar o include poro assim como você está fazendo, pois é preciso levar em conta algumas coisas como, a partir de que local você está chamando estes arquivo. Coloque o por exemplo include_once(__DIR__  . "DAO/dalA.php");. para os includes que fizer.